# Why does Clang warn: `'&&' within '||'`?

Tags: c, clang

My understanding is the parentheses make no difference, so is there any reason (other than to “improve“ code-clarity) that Clang warns this as a default? I prefer not to add the parentheses as I dislike adding code for code’s sake.

```
src/websocket.c:420:43: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
        if (rv == 0 && N != 0 || rv == -1 && errno == ECONNRESET) {
                              ~~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/websocket.c:420:43: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to
      silence this warning
        if (rv == 0 && N != 0 || rv == -1 && errno == ECONNRESET) {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: How about adding code for *clarity's* sake?  Parentheses here would help people who don't remember the rules about precedence of `&&` and `||` (which don't all that often come up).

Comment: I’m all for adding code to improve clarity. Personally however, I find the additional visual noise of the unnecessary parentheses reduces clarity in this case. When I see the extra parentheses I immediately scan the whole line looking for a reason for them, when I find none I then have to ponder for a while if I read it wrong or if the code in question is merely trying to “help” me to understand the operator precedence, that I already knew. This code is *definitely* not for inexperienced coders, most of the people reading it will be at my level, and thus I assume will feel the same.

Comment: Although the point about clarity is a valid one, it seems strange to warn for a perfectly legal code as per the rules of the language.

Comment: @KingsIndian: Kinda does seem strange.  But i don't know if i've ever seen a compiler just output a `note:` without a `warning:`.   There might not be such a thing as a compiler notice (ie: a message that's not a warning or error, but just something the compiler thinks you ought to be made aware of).  If there's such a thing, the message ought to be at that level.

Comment: @KingsIndian Compilers also warn about `if (x = 3)`, which is perfectly legal. The point is, it's deemed something that people often get wrong, so the compiler writers decided it's worth a warning.

Comment: Parentheses make no difference *if present*, like `{ }` around one-line `if` statements. They increase clarity of expression and decrease the chance of programmer and compiler misunderstanding each other. What Clang does here is telling you, "this *could* be understood either way; are you sure you got it right?". Adding parentheses states that, yes, you got it right. Disabling the warning, on the other hand, just removes the safety net. **I** know the precedence rules, but when I see code *without* parentheses, I wonder if the other guy knew them too...

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand *why* compiler does that. Personally, a situation like this would annoy me when I am forced to add a couple of brackets as I *always* fix warnings.

Comment: I always fix warnings also, and find it ridiculous that people are advocating I add unnecessary code to help people who have failed to learn important things like *operator precedence*. Heaven forbid I ever employ such a terrible programmer.

Comment: We’ll have to agree to disagree here. `C` is not a forgiving language, I expect anyone reading my `C` to know operator precedence and to expect **me** to know operator precedence also. In case you think I am somehow advocating writing unclear code, then of course I am not. Clarity is very important in code. However as I already explained in my above comment, I don't think the extra parenthesis help anything here. In a case where I would think more clarity was required I'd be more likely to memo out the && groupings into local boolean variables. **THAT** would make it clearer.

Comment: @KingsIndian Agreed, the relative precedence of `&&` and `||` is pretty fundamental (not quite as fundamental as `*` over `+`), and the warning here is a little too paranoid. Still, the compiler warning about dubious constructs is a good thing, IMO, as long as one can turn the warning off.

Comment: Warning about `if (a = 0)` is an entirely different category of warning. Can anyone even imagine a situation where something like `if (a = 0)` would be desired?

Comment: Why is everyone defending this warning so vehemently?  How would you feel if the compiler warned you every time you said "2 + 3 * 4"?  It's beyond ludicrous.  The assumption is that programmers have a *basic* understanding of the language they're working with and don't need visual clutter to understand precedence.  On another note, Xcode doesn't seem to provide an option to disable this by default...

Comment: Amen to all of you who think this warning is stupid.  I can't believe I'm have to deal with a warning for writing correct code, particularly one that's so obviously geared towards newbie programmers.  Code ought to run poorly if you don't know the operator precedence table.  Having to debug errors like this when I was learning was exactly the thing that proved to me the importance of memorizing the OPT!  I think this feature condones laziness.

Comment: C, C++, Java, Java, Javascript, C#, and Go all give && higher precedence than ||, consistent with traditional mathematics.  Clutter is not clarity -- Xcode ought to make it easier to turn off this irksome warning.

Comment: I begrudgingly added parens (the precedence rule seems logical), and lo, my semicolon ended up at exactly column 80. Sadly all of our code gets auto-ugified at 80 upon saving.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The natural tendency is to read it left to right, and it's easy to forget the operator precedence. That said, it's just a warning, and if you know what you're doing and your own style allows it, feel free to suppress it.

Comment: For those who would like to suppress it, append: `-Wno-logical-op-parentheses` to your build-system’s CFLAGS.

Answer (score 28):

I'm guessing because it's simply a bit unclear, unless the reader is very good at [C's operator precedence rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence).

Your expression is like this:

```
if (A && B || C && D)
```

and since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, it means

```
if ((A && B) || (C && D))
```

which I guess is what you mean, but it's not very clear when reading.

Comment: IMHO anyone who studied basic logic at least a bit should remember that in maths, AND has higher precedence than OR. I think the compiler is being quite paranoid here. (I. e., this is definitely not the same case as `if (a = 0)`.)

Comment: Totally agree - this is the most useless warning I've ever seen. Why does it allow to write 1+2*3 and doesn't suggest to change it to 1+(2*3) ?

Comment: Probably because in the real world most coders are pretty sure what `1+2*3` does exactly, while most of them are not sure what `a && b || c && d` will do exactly.

Comment: When `&&` and `||` are not overloaded, however, isn't `A && B || C && D` interpreted more like `if (A && B) { return true; } else if (C && D) { return true; } else { return false; }`? Saying that `&&` has higher precedence *somewhat* implies that `C && D` will be evaluated before the `||`, but my current understanding is that a more accurate translation would be `A && (B || (C && D))`. This distinction, of course, is only relevant for nano-optimizations. Either way, the most important takeaway of the warning is definitely that `A && (B || C) && D` is an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: @M-Pixel `A && (B || (C && D))` isn't even equivalent. This will evaluate to false whenever `A` is false, while the original would be true as long as `C` and `D` are both true.

Comment: Oops, you're right.