# How to fix the warning: '&&' within '||'

Tags: c, gcc

Is this a problem with GCC? I have tried running on Windows and it doesn't raise this warning. Is there a way (except from inserting the parentheses) around this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x, y;

int main (void)
{
x = 3;
y = 7;

if ((y < 2) || (y > 5) && (x < 12)) {
    printf ("Yes\n");
} else
    printf ("Nope\n");
return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
/Users/filename:18:28: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    if ((y < 2) || (y > 5) && (x < 12)) {
                ~~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/filename:18:28: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to
      silence this warning
    if ((y < 2) || (y > 5) && (x < 12)) {
                           ^
                   (                  )
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error,

Comment: Voted to reopen, because the OP explicitly asks how to fix the warning on GCC except inserting the parentheses, and the linked question is for Clang and proposed there solutions do not work for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16939939/3893016):

> The natural tendency is to read it left to right, and it's easy to forget the operator precedence. That said, **it's just a warning**, and if you know what you're doing and your own style allows it, feel free to suppress it.

And to suppress it:

> For those who would like to suppress it, append: `-Wno-logical-op-parentheses` to your build-system’s **CFLAGS**

Comment: -1 because the OP explicitly asks about the way to fix this on **GCC**, which do not support the Clang `no-logical-op-parentheses` flag.